# PHP - variable from GET is changing

Tags: php, get

I have a svg.php file with some shapes.

```
<rect onclick="window.location='search.php?filter=1'" width="50" height="50">
<rect onclick="window.location='search.php?filter=2'" width="50" height="50">
```

Search.php

```
div class="container">
            <textarea class="search" id="search_id"></textarea>
                <div id="result"></div> 
          <?php include("svg.php"); ?>
</div>

//This is for a autocomplete search, took it from http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/08/autocomplete-search-using-php-mysql-and.html

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $(".search").keyup(function() { 
        var search_id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search='+ search_id;

        if (search_id=='') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_database.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).hide(); }
            });
        };

        if(search_id!='') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_database.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show(); }
            });
        }return false;    
    });

    jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#search_id').val(decoded);
    });

    jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
            jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    $('#search_id').click(function(){
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});

</script> 

Then a search_database.php

    $search = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET["filter"] : 1;

    echo $search; //echos "2". 

    if ($search=="1") {
        echo $search; //enters if, and it's not supposed to, and echos "1"
        Select * from table;
    }
```

Search_database.php

```
$search = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET["filter"] : "1";

echo $search //echos "2";

if ($search=="1") {

    $q = $_POST['search'];
    $q_length = strlen($q);

    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM table
    LIMIT 6

SQL;

if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>

<div class="show_search">
    <?php  echo $row['name'] ?> </a>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

I'm on `search.php?filter=2` and the first echo is correct ("2") but for some reason it keeps entering the If Clause and echos that $search is "1".

I'm not defining the $search variable anywhere else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is defined within the `$_POST` array? Which element of the `$_POST` array are you checking for the value `1` ?

Comment: You use `$_GET`, but you check for `$_POST` ? Where is the logic?

Comment: Why are you doing `if($_POST AND $search=="1")`?  Why are you using `AND` instead of `&&` there?  The `AND` might not be operating the way you think it does.  Why do you have `Select * from table;` there like that?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the first if clause. You have to close `)` twice, not only once

Comment: I'll remove the Post and fix the syntax error.

Comment: You need to show us a reduced test case that actually demonstrates the problem. This does not.

Comment: BTW: You direct to `search.php` and we are looking at the script: `search_database.php`

Comment: Edited. Here's the whole script now

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit too complicated.

```
$search = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET["filter"] : 1;

if($search == 1) {
    echo $search;
}
```

Thats enough, you don't need the check if `$_POST` is available. That make not so much sense because you don't send a form and you don't have post data in that case when you it with `window.location`.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: I had correct that but you were fast :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed it but it's doing the same thing

Comment: @Stony: I'm a ninja ^~^

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other code between following two lines:

```
 echo $search; //echos "2".
```

AND

```
 if ($_POST AND $search=="1") { ... }
```

Then, its not possible to go inside `if` condition. its only possible if your `if` condition is like `if($_POST AND $search=1)`. Check that, whether you have single `=` or double `==` in comparing `$search` variable.

---

If there is some php code in between, then show us, whatever it is, so that we can help you.